# TensorFlowNET: IndexOutOfRangeException in TransferLearningWithInceptionV3 example

Tags: c#, tensorflow

During the execution of TransferLearningWithInceptionV3 IndexOutOfRangeException is thrown.

The version of SciSharp-Stack-Examples is from 8 Jan 2022.

[The screenshot with exception](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/5b_-OIBzWaD16w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the framework, they use feature vector caching and store it in txt as the sequence of comma-separated floats.

But in my culture decimal separator is also a comma. So this file is read incorrectly.

The error can be fixed if to apply culture that separates decimal part with a dot:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
```